# Atomic number ranges in "integral units"?

Tags: atoms, terminology

My textbook says the following:

> For an electrically neutral or complete atom, the atomic number also equals the number of electrons. This atomic number ranges in integral units from 1 for hydrogen to 92 for uranium, the highest of the naturally occurring elements.

I'm wondering what is meant by "integral units" in this context?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please clarify this.

Comment: It means the said number can be 1, or 10, or 25, but never 1.5.

Comment: @IvanNeretin In that case, I think the word they're look for is "discrete", not "integral".

Comment: No, it should be just integers. "Integral number" looks like literal translation from another language.

Comment: @Mithoron Yes, the word "integral" doesn't even have a grammatical connection to the word "integers", which makes its usage very unusual.

Comment: If the author has used "integral units of charge" it would have been much better. Definition [1b(1)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/integral) at Merriam-Webster.

Comment: @ThePointer Integral can be used to mean "of or relating to integers". An example of this usage in mathematics is the concept of an [integral domain](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/MT4517/Lectures/L4.html)

Comment: @ThePointer "discrete" is not the same thing as "integers"; 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 ... is discrete. I also second what Tyberius has said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a way of saying that the atomic number will never be a decimal number like 1.5 or 16.8

One consequence is that if you carry out an experiment which gives you a decimal number as an atomic number, then you must have a mixture or something is wrong.